# How to modify ip of PADDRINFOA structure

Tags: c++

I hooked **getaddrinfo** function and I want modify the ip of *ppResult*.

```
f_getaddrinfo(PCSTR pNodeName, PCSTR pServiceName, const ADDRINFOA  *pHints, PADDRINFOA *ppResult) {

    // REAL FUNCTION
    r_getaddrinfo(pNodeName,pServiceName,pHints,ppResult);

    // FAIL
    sockaddr_in addrIn;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &addrIn.sin_addr);
    const_cast<PADDRINFOA>(*ppResult)->ai_addr = (struct sockaddr*)&addrIn.sin_addr;

    // FAIL
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", const_cast<PADDRINFOA>(*ppResult)->ai_addr);
}
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: And what goes wrong with your code?

Comment: @freakish I tried -> error "expression must have pointer-to-class type"

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `PADDRINFOA*`!!! `PADDRINFOA` is already a pointer to `ADDRINFOA`, you actually have double pointer now. Actually stick to `struct addrinfo*` which is portable.

Anyway try this:

```
PADDRINFOA result = *ppResult;  // Should not do that, ppResult should be PADDRINFOA
struct sockaddr_in* addr = reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in*>(result->ai_addr);
inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &(addr->sin_addr));
```

Comment: compilation error "expression must have pointer-to-class type"

Comment: @NewCoder30 OMG, why is your `ppResult` object a `PADDRINFOA*`??? `PADDRINFOA` is already a pointer to `ADDRINFOA`. Anyway I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, Work!!!, Sorry I'm learning C/++ Programming and I dunno some things. I will study more.

Comment: @NewCoder30 Right, my bad. Sometimes I forget that there was a time when I was a beginner as well. :) Feel free to ask more questions. Good luck!

Comment: No problem, Thanks so much bro.!